# Oauth - oauth_verifier

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't see a mechanism for providing the oauth_verifier field in the Google Apps OAuthService and UrlFetchApp objects.

I'm trying to connect to Yammer using code based on the Twitter example. I get through the auth process and get a Verification Code back from Yammer. I'm not sure how to get this back into the Google Apps script and included with the access token request.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth support built into UrlFetch expects that the OAuth provider redirects you back to Apps Script with the verifier in the URL. I'm not sure why Yammer is instead providing it to you to paste in, but there is to place in the interface to enter it.